# How does Log42 async logger behaves on sudden shutdown of application?

Tags: java, asynchronous, logging, log4j2

For asynchronous logging, what happens to the logs that are not yet written to the destination appender and the application/system goes down? Do we loose these logs (since they are in memory) or is there a way to recover them?

I don't want to loose any ERROR level logging. So my next question is: Is there a way to configure sync and async logging for a single appender at log level? For e.g. I want my file appender to perform ERROR level logging synchronously while INFO/DEBUG asynchronously?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the process dies gracefully, all events in the queue will be processed. See [this code](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/AsyncLoggerDisruptor.html#L116) for how AsyncLogger shutdown works in detail.

If the process is not allowed to do cleanup (`kill -9` for example) then you may lose events. Such is life.

If you want ERROR level log events processed synchronously but other levels asynchronously you may not be able to use AsyncLoggers but you can use AsyncAppender. You can configure the Logger(s) to route to both a FileAppender and an AsyncAppender. The AsyncAppender routes to the FileAppender. Then use Filters to make the AsyncAppender only accept INFO and below, while the FileAppender accepts ERROR and above.

Comment: Thanks! What is the impact of performance when you use mix of sync and async appenders (as described above) vs all sync loggers (only for ERROR level)? Also, async appenders doesn't use LMAX Disruptor technology (instead use ArrayBlockingQueue) - so is it still advisable to use hybrid approach?

Comment: To clarify, our application is on Log4j 1.x and are planning to update to async logging in Log4J 2.x. At present, we only use sync appenders (Console and JDBC) in our application and because of thread contention lock problem in Log4J 1.x, we set log level to ERROR in our production deployments. Because of ERROR log level, it is hard to debug any issue in prod deployment. We are thinking to upgrade to Log4J 2.x and use async logging so that we can turn on INFO/DEBUG logging in prod deployments.

Comment: Be aware that both Console appender and JDBC appender are slow. Asynchronous logging allows you to quickly enqueue events without thread contention, which is nice, but slow appenders means your queue will fill up when your app is busy. Queue is presized to be big, but once it is full you need to either block until space becomes available or start dropping events (see AsyncQueueFullPolicy). Async Loggers will not help you if you need to log more than the underlying appenders can keep up with. If you need to log a lot, consider logging to a file with all loggers Async (using the Disruptor).

Comment: Thanks! Just curious, why console appender (which I assume is sysout or syserr) is considered slow vs logging to a file (which involves I/O)? Moreover, what is the recommended approach of writing log information to the database (if JDBC appender is considered slow)? Our web application pulls out the data from log database table and show it in UI for user review.

Comment: No problem! Console logging: this is not my opinion, I measured it. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html#tradeoffs   Console logging is 50X (!) slower than file logging. Dangerous to use in production!

Comment: Jdbc logging: you could use a fast database/JDBC driver combination. NoSQL databases have a reputation for fast throughput, logging may be a good use case. I doubt that any database will be faster than file logging though. If this becomes a performance bottleneck you could consider changing your web application to read/tail a log file instead of a database.

Comment: What is the disadvantage of using async appender vs all asynchronous loggers? If I use the approach described by you in the answer - will it provide better performance than using all synchronous logging?

Comment: Async Loggers use the LMAX Disruptor and give the best performance. Another advantage of Async Loggers is that they are garbage free. AsyncAppender lacks these advantages.

Comment: Thanks! Our current application uses Log4J 1.x sync appenders which has content lock problem in multithreading environment. Does it make sense to move to Log4j 2.x even though I will use mix of sync and async appender? Does Log4j 2.x sync appender have problem of content lock in multithreading environment (similar to Log4j 1.x)?

Comment: Log4j 1.x is End of Life so it always makes sense to upgrade. Not aware of any deadlock issues on Log4j2.

Comment: Thank you! One last question - how does other applications handle the scenario where they don't want to loose the logs due to abrupt shutdown? Don't they use all async loggers in their application at all? I believe ERROR level logging is always important for any application and no matter what - you don't want to loose it in any case.

Comment: Hi Remko, can you please share your thoughts on above question?

Comment: For audit logging, where it is crucial that all log events are persisted, asynchronous logging is not the best choice and people use synchronous logging. For most applications however, the log file is used for trouble shooting and you have a choice. You'll need to make a trade off between performance and the chances of being able to diagnose issues when your application crashes. Crashes like that are rare and rather than the application log file you are more likely to diagnose the cause of a JVM crash by looking at the JVM crash dump file.

Comment: Agree, but some of our customers perform scheduled maintenance of their systems where they restart the system where our application is installed. In that case, there is no JVM crash but we may loose some our logs due to sudden shutdown of the system. Not sure how to address it! The solution that you have suggested makes use of sync (for error) and async appenders (for info and debug) which itself is subjected to content locks under high loads. Thoughts?

Comment: If the system shuts down the application gracefully all log events will be persisted to disk by the JVM shutdown hook that Log4j2 installs (for non-web applications). If not shut down gracefully then it sounds to me that those final log events are not considered important enough to wait for so they can be discarded, no?